# Can you use JDBC to connect to just an instance without specifying a database?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am working on an JAVA app that evaluates the data and log sizes of all databases on an instance and mails a monthly report. I am currently working with SQLServer2014. I am using an SQL query that calculates the size of all databases by querying sys.master_files.

The problem is that when using JDBC to make the query, it returns the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost"
```

I have tried connecting to particular databases and that works fine. Is there any way to do this query directly to sys.master_files using JDBC? Or is there a smarter way altogether to accomplish the same result?

Thanks

Comment: Typically the RDBMS running with your application is known when you deploy.  Can you elaborate on why you think you need this?

Comment: Your URL is wrong, the correct URL for SQL Server starts with `jdbc:sqlserver:`, not `jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver:`; look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url for the correct URL; and according to that documentation, the database name is optional (it will then connect to the default database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "No suitable driver found" error is simply due to a malformed connection URL. `jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver` is not valid.

As for connecting to an instance without specifying a particular database, this works fine for me:

```java
// NB: no databaseName specified in the following
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;integratedSecurity=true";  

try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)) {
    String sql = "SELECT name FROM sys.master_files WHERE type_desc='ROWS' ORDER BY database_id";
    try (
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql)) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Note that `sys.master_files` is a system view that is available in all databases, so AFAIK it doesn't matter what the current database (catalog) is when you call it.